# Serial Port With Electron-Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron

I tried to do serial port to listen my COMports with electron-vue.js.
When I try to code this below.

```
const SerialPort = require("serialport");
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;

const port = new SerialPort("COM3", {
    baudRate: 9600,
});

const parser = new Readline();
port.pipe(parser);

//Read Data
parser.on("data", (line) => {
    console.log(line);
});

//Send Data
parser.write("Sended Data !");
```

I got this below error in console.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined
> at Object.eval (bindings.js?dfc1:29)
> at eval (bindings.js:223)
> at Object../node_modules/bindings/bindings.js (0.js:231)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:854)
> at fn (app.js:151)
> at eval (linux.js?88eb:2)
> at Object../node_modules/@serialport/bindings/lib/linux.js (0.js:65)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:854)
> at fn (app.js:151)
> at Object.eval (index.js?c888:14)

How can I solve this problem ?

By the way, When I try to run this code in node.js, it runs. But when I try to run this code in Vue.js, it did not run.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

serialport uses physical resource so can't be webpacked as client package.  you need to mark serialport as external for the builder.

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: ["serialport"],
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: where am I gonna write this code in my electron project ?

Comment: @SefaUn did you figure out where to put this?

Comment: @NevilleBamshoot I actually dont know. but I guess, we have to put this to webpack. if you solve this, could you answer this question ?

Comment: you should put this inside vue.config.js
like this:

// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: ["serialport"],
    },
  },
}